# How to configure Profiler in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, profiler

I'm having trouble to configure the profiler in Magento 2 (version 1.0.0-beta). I want to apply a specific configuration, I want to set a timer threshold to 0 because the default settings prevent from seeing timer below 0.001s.

```
$config = [
    'baseDir' => BP,
    'drivers' => [
        ['output' =>
            [
                'type' => 'html',
                ['thresholds' => ['sum' => 0.00000001]],
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'driverFactory'
];
Magento\Framework\Profiler::applyConfig($config, BP);
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html#dirs-introduction

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the specific array config to pass to applyConfig in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the right configuration options.

```
$config = [
    'drivers' => [
        [
            'output' => [
                'type' => 'html',
                'thresholds' => [
                    'sum' => 0.0000001
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'driverFactory'
];
Magento\Framework\Profiler::applyConfig($config, BP);
```

By submitting this array, I'm asking the profiler to display the result in HTML format with a threshold of min time of 0.0000001s of execution.